# Get error Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' when try to initiate Google maps from "run" method in Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I have following service that initiate Google maps:

```
app.service('mapService', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
            var self = this;
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
            self.map = false;
            self.panorama = false;
            self.center = null;

            self.initialize = function(map_id) {
                    var options = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                            zoom: 3,
                            scaleControl: true,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    self.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), options);
                    // ^^^ here get error 
                     };
     ....
```

My `app.js` looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('cntsApp', []); //['AngularGM']

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/mapboard', {templateUrl: config.base_url + 'app/partials/cnts.html', controller: 'CntsCtrl'});                
        }]);


app.run([
    '$rootScope',
    '$window',
    'mapService',
    function($rootScope, $window, mapService) {

       mapService.initialize("heatmapAreaA");

        }]);
```

As you can see I call `mapService.initialize(/**/)` from `app.run` but get Exception:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

From other posts its mean that Google maps still didn't render and I need wait till DOM will finish.

How can I achieve that in my case?

**[EDIT]**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="CntsCtrl">

    <div class="container" style="width: 96%">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-2 column">
                        Config
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 column">
                        <div id="heatmapAreaA" ></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 column">
                        Chart
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From controller the line: `mapService.initialize("heatmapAreaA"); works fine.`

Thanks,

Comment: Did you every get this working as I have the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it, but my guess is your view html hasn't completely been compiled by Angular, therefor Google Maps can't find your div to display the map in. Try putting the

```
mapService.initialize("heatmapAreaA");
```

call in a controller for your view and put the call in a $timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
  mapService.initialize("heatmapAreaA"); 
});
```

This way the call gets fired after the controller has run and your view has been compiled.